# Sockets with IPv6

Tags: c, sockets, winsock2

How to create and bind socket using winsock2, which will be receiving only packets which use ipv6 protocol.

Regards

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737937(v=vs.85).aspx? This seems like everything you need or is there a something specific that does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything about network sockets and even windows specific stuff can be found at [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). Transition from IPv4 to IPv6 is described in detail [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/ip4to6.html)